# What causes a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError for sun.misc.Unsafe.registerNatives?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, jetty

I have a Spring-based web application I am trying to deploy on Jetty 9.3 inside a Docker image. It deploys fine on Tomcat 8, but in Jetty I get an error I am unable to debug:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.misc.Unsafe.registerNatives()V
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.registerNatives(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.<clinit>(Unsafe.java:48)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.infinispan.util.CollectionFactory.<clinit>(CollectionFactory.java:109)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.MarshallableTypeHints.<init>(MarshallableTypeHints.java:47)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.AbstractMarshaller.<init>(AbstractMarshaller.java:39)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.VersionAwareMarshaller.<init>(VersionAwareMarshaller.java:62)
```

At first I assumed something was wrong with the JVM installation, but I have tried with a couple of different versions of OpenJDK (8u66, 8u60) and also with the Oracle JVM.

If I run a test class that accesses `sun.misc.Unsafe`, there is no error. So it must be related to Jetty as well.

I am leaning towards this being a class loader issue, but I am wondering how this error can occur for internal JVM classes?

---

Update: Not sure if it is helpful, but running with `-verbose:jni` shows that natives in sun.misc.Unsafe are registered at an earlier point:

```
[Dynamic-linking native method sun.misc.Unsafe.registerNatives ... JNI]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getObject]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putObject]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getObjectVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putObjectVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getBoolean]
...
```

---

Another update: I should point out that I am using a number of low-level features, such as ASM (due to Hibernate), and AspectJ Load-time weaving. Perhaps this affects the loading somehow? I can see this in my log file before the issue occurs:

```
[Loaded sun.misc.Unsafe from __JVM_DefineClass__]
```

whereas it has previously been loaded from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/rt.jar. I guess this can be related?

Comment: Have you tried running your program with -Xcheck:jni JVM option? please share your input.

Comment: I don't get any new information, except a few "WARNING in native method: JNI call made without checking exceptions when required to from CallStaticObjectMethod" when booting jetty. The exception is thrown much later, when deploying the WAR file. However, I have added information when running the JVM with the -verbose:jni option.

Comment: is your infinispan being loaded by your WebApp (and its isolated ClassLoader) or the server (and its top level ClassLoader)?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: The web app ClassLoader.

Comment: Check your classpath for duplicate (and conflicting) `sun/misc/Unsafe.class` files. (commonly seen with jrockit, jboss, weblogic, cglib, and akka use)